Getting KerberosAuthException: failure to login on spark submit in kubernetes cluster mode
I am getting below exception when submitting jar file using spark-submit command in cluster mode.

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.security.KerberosAuthException: failure to login: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: java.lang.NullPointerException: invalid null input: name

I am trying to submit spark-examples_2.12-3.5.3.jar on AWS kubernetes cluster. I have created a job-submit pod with bitnami spark 3.5.3 version and from this pod I am running below job submit command in cluster mode.
version details:

spark version: 3.5.3
Scala version 2.12.18
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 17.0.12

spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
--conf spark.kubernetes.executor.deleteOnTermination=false \
--conf spark.kubernetes.maxFailedPods=0 \
--conf spark.executor.instances=1 \
--conf spark.executor.memory=2g \
--conf spark.executor.cores=1 \
--conf spark.kubernetes.namespace=test-namespace \
--conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=bitnami/spark:latest \
--conf spark.jars=s3a://test-bucket/spark/jars/*/spark-examples_2.12-3.5.3.jar \
--conf spark.kubernetes.file.upload.path=s3a://test-bucket/spark/jars \
--master k8s://https://xxxxxxx-api-server:443 \
--deploy-mode cluster \
./examples/jars/spark-examples_2.12-3.5.3.jar

On kubernetes cluster, driver pod is getting created and then executor pods which are going into error. Below are the executor logs where I can see exception

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.security.KerberosAuthException: failure to login: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: java.lang.NullPointerException: invalid null input: name

complete executor log:
INFO KubernetesExecutorBackend: Started daemon with process name: 1@spark-pi-98017c930a421dde-exec-1
INFO SignalUtils: Registering signal handler for TERM
INFO SignalUtils: Registering signal handler for HUP
INFO SignalUtils: Registering signal handler for INT
WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.security.KerberosAuthException: failure to login: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: java.lang.NullPointerException: invalid null input: name
        at jdk.security.auth/com.sun.security.auth.UnixPrincipal.<init>(UnixPrincipal.java:71)
        at jdk.security.auth/com.sun.security.auth.module.UnixLoginModule.login(UnixLoginModule.java:134)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:755)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:679)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:677)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:677)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$HadoopLoginContext.login(UserGroupInformation.java:2065)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doSubjectLogin(UserGroupInformation.java:1975)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.createLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:719)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:669)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:579)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.createSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.KubernetesExecutorBackend$.run(KubernetesExecutorBackend.scala:67)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.KubernetesExecutorBackend$.main(KubernetesExecutorBackend.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.KubernetesExecutorBackend.main(KubernetesExecutorBackend.scala)

        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doSubjectLogin(UserGroupInformation.java:1986)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.createLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:719)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:669)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:579)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.createSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.KubernetesExecutorBackend$.run(KubernetesExecutorBackend.scala:67)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.KubernetesExecutorBackend$.main(KubernetesExecutorBackend.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.KubernetesExecutorBackend.main(KubernetesExecutorBackend.scala)
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: java.lang.NullPointerException: invalid null input: name
        at jdk.security.auth/com.sun.security.auth.UnixPrincipal.<init>(UnixPrincipal.java:71)
        at jdk.security.auth/com.sun.security.auth.module.UnixLoginModule.login(UnixLoginModule.java:134)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:755)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:679)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:677)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:677)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$HadoopLoginContext.login(UserGroupInformation.java:2065)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doSubjectLogin(UserGroupInformation.java:1975)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.createLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:719)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:669)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:579)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.createSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.KubernetesExecutorBackend$.run(KubernetesExecutorBackend.scala:67)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.KubernetesExecutorBackend$.main(KubernetesExecutorBackend.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.KubernetesExecutorBackend.main(KubernetesExecutorBackend.scala)

        at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:850)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:679)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:677)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:677)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$HadoopLoginContext.login(UserGroupInformation.java:2065)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doSubjectLogin(UserGroupInformation.java:1975)
        ... 8 more

Expectation:
I don't know what is this kerberos authentication and why it is needed here. I want to skip this part and should be able to submit the job. Anything I am missing here?

check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41864985/hadoop-ioexception-failure-to-login

Hi @Ejaj Have you been able to solve this? I am getting the same error and is kind of clueless...

Hi @s510 I think the issue is with bitnami/spark images that i was using. I switched to apache/spark-py image and it started working.
